# Roots of Arbitrary Numbers

Tags: code-golf, math, number

One day, when I was bored in maths class, I learned of a neat trick for solving the real cube root of a number!

Let's use the number \$79,507\$ as an example.

First, take digit in the one's place and compare it to this table:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
\text{Extracted Digit} &\text{Resulting Digit} \\
\hline
\text{1} &\text{1} \\
\text{2} &\text{8} \\
\text{3} &\text{7} \\
\text{4} &\text{4} \\
\text{5} &\text{5} \\
\text{6} &\text{6} \\
\text{7} &\text{3} \\
\text{8} &\text{2} \\
\text{9} &\text{9} \\
\text{0} &\text{0} \\
\hline
\end{array}

In this example, the `Resulting Digit` will be \$3\$ since the extracted digit is \$7\$.

Next, remove all digits that are less than \$10^3\$:

$$ 79507 → 79 $$

Then, find the largest perfect cube that does not exceed the input:

$$ 64 < 79 $$

\$64=4^3\$, thus the next digit needed is \$4\$.

Finally, multiply the digit found in the previous step by \$10\$ and add the `Resulting Digit` found in the first step:

$$ 10*4+3=43 $$

Thus, the cube root of \$79,507\$ equals \$43\$.

***However***, there a neat quirk about this trick: it doesn't apply to *only* cubed numbers.  In fact, it works with all \$n>1\$ where \$n\bmod2\ne0\$.

The steps mentioned above can be summed up in this generalization for an \$n\$ power:

- Step 1) Take the digit in the one's place in the input.  Compare it to the one's place digit of the \$n\$th powers of \$1\$ to \$10\$, then use the corresponding digit.
- Step 2) Remove all digits of the input less than \$10^n\$.  Compare the resulting number to the perfect powers definied in *Step 1*.  Use the \$n\$th root of the largest perfect power less than said number.  (Largest perfect power can exceed \$10^n\$)
- Step 3) Multiply the number from *Step 2* by 10 then add the number from *Step 1*.  This will be the final result.

## Task

Given two positive integers \$n\$ and \$m\$, return the \$n\$th root of \$m\$.

**Input:**

- Two positive integers \$n\$ and \$m\$.
- \$m\$ is guaranteed to be a perfect \$n\$th power of an integer.
- \$n\$ is guaranteed to be odd and greater than \$2\$.  (This method doesn't work if \$n\$ is even.)

**Output:**

- The values calculated in steps 1 and 2.
- The \$n\$th root of \$m\$.
- Output can be on multiples lines or a list, whichever is more convenient.

**Rules:**

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the fewer bytes, the better!
- [Standard I/O](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) rules apply.
- The output ***must*** be calculated using the aforementioned method.
- No builtins allowed that already calculate this.  A prime example being TI-BASIC's [x√ command](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/xroot).

**Examples:**

```
Input      | Output
-------------------
3, 79507   | 3
           | 4
           | 43
3, 79507   | [3, 4, 43]
5, 4084101 | 1
           | 2
           | 21
5, 4084101 | [1, 2, 21]
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17641/85765) post.

Comment: Are we allowed to use a built-in root command for step 2? Or are we only allowed to compute numbers to the \$n\$th power and compare?

Comment: Do `x` using `y` challenges are frowned upon usually as per meta consensus (as it is often difficult to enforce that they've gotten to `x` using `y` only).

Comment: I second @MagicOctopusUrn 's comment about "Do X with method Y" challenges; also I'd note that this trick works with \$n=1\$ although it is of course trivial.

Comment: To make the algorithm requirement observable, you could require that our code output the results of specific intermediate steps.

Comment: @RobinRyder yes, you are allowed to use a built-in root method to get the 10's place digit as is described in *Step 2*, but nothing else

Comment: @xnor i didn't include a requirement for printing out the intermediate steps; the source code will be able to show whether the method was used or not.

Comment: However, if the general consensus deems it necessary, I will edit the challenge to include this.

Comment: Requirement added.

Comment: Well... One could now compute \$x=m^{1/n}\$ with a built-in and output \$[floor(x/10),x\bmod 10]\$...

Comment: @Arnauld "No builtins allowed that already calculate this.  A prime example being TI-BASIC's x√ command".  What i meant by my response to **RobinRyder** was that you can use a root function to get the 10's place digit, but you can't use it for *Step 1*'s value.

Comment: My point is that using the required algorithm is still non-observable.

Comment: Hm, fair point.  I suppose that this was a very subjective challenge in the first place.

Comment: You may want to add a couple smaller test cases, `3, 1 = [1,0,1]` and `5, 32 = [2, 0 2]`

Comment: And the sandbox didn't catch the issues...what else is new???

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

Saved 1 byte thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*

```
mθ=²¹°÷DÝ¹m@O<=ìï=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9vc2FiaWX//23OuD3CssK5wrDDt0TDncK5bUBPPD3DrMOvPf//Mwo3OTUwNw)

Comment: As per general consensus, the challenge has been edited to require the printing of intermediate steps.

Comment: `‹_` can be `@` to save a byte.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: What! I am 100% certain that didn't work when I tried it before :(

Comment: @Tau: Now prints intermediate results.

Comment: Not really in spec with the challenge, but just putting it out there: **9 bytes**: [`zmò¤,D¨,,`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/KvfwpkNLdFwOrdDR@f/flMvI0NLIxMTCwNjUHAA) or [`zmòÐ¨sθr»`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/KvfwpsMTDq0oPrej6NDu//9NuYwMLY1MTCwMjE3NAQ)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES7),  <s>58</s>  56 bytes

*Saved <s>11</s> many bytes thanks to @Emigna*

Takes input as `(m)(n)`. Returns the 2 intermediate values and the final result as an array.

```javascript
m=>g=(n,k)=>k**n>m/10**n?[u=m**n%10,--k,k*10+u]:g(n,-~k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrBCgIhEIDhV5lL4JimYrEUjD1IdFi2XalZNdq2Y69u0unjh//Rf/pleN2fb53LbawT1UQhksiKkQJLmUMyzjbPl5VSc@Os0poVS2e36/UU26u/jHUoeSnzuJtLFJPojgfbofCIYAz8Cwj2HqQEX38)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 62 bytes

This version uses BigInts as I/O to support larger inputs.

```javascript
m=>g=(n,k=0n)=>k**n>m/10n**n?[u=m**n%10n,--k,k*10n+u]:g(n,++k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VctBDoIwEAXQvaeYjUlbqG0FgpoMHsS4IAgEC1Mj4vXrYNy4mfn/J@9ev@u5eQ6Pl6Zwa2OHccKqR0GpR0sSK68UVZNxljicLwtO/LdcU6196hWnZLmeehZJ4mVsAs1hbHdj6EUnymNhS5IiIykBwBg@3w0Q8gyUgmzzL3J7yJ11bIrVsPgtLPZuFUX8AA)

Comment: As per general consensus, the challenge has been edited to require the printing of intermediate steps.

Comment: This fails when the final digit is a `0`. For example `f(1000,3)` returns `0` instead of `10`.

Comment: @RobinRyder Should be fixed now. (However, the 58-byte version only support very small inputs.)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 74 bytes

```r
function(m,n)c(a<-match(m%%10,(1:9)^n%%10,0),b<-(m/10^n)^(1/n)%/%1,a+10*b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcZRCoAgDADQ0whbTdyIEKOuIqgg9eGCsPMb9L7eM@ox6qulX7dCI8UCabct9XJCM0aYQLaAUf8zUt4tNCccFSOIUzTOCKVZeMo4KviwsqcFxwc)

`match(m%%10,(1:9)^n%%10,0)` compares the last digit of `m`  to the reference table (and outputs `0` if no match is found), thus performing step 1.

`(m/10^n)^(1/n)%/%1` gives the output of step 2.

Comment: clever use of `nomatch`, although of course `match(...,(0:9)^n%%10)-1` would be just as golfy

Comment: @Giuseppe Yes, I had that version initially as well, but decided I liked the version with `nomatch` better. :-)